# Pass a List<T> to a MultiBinding converter in wpf

Tags: wpf, multibinding

I have a List as a property on my ViewModel.I want to pass this List to as a parameter to a TextBlock via MultiBinding in XAML.How can this be done?

```
 <DataGrid VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" x:Name="Dg_Prices" CanUserReorderColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentRec.Current_Item_Price_Details}"  CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="false" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="False" >
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Percentage(%)" Width="1,*" x:Name="Percentage">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <DataGridCell >
                                            <ContentControl >
                                                <TextBlock Width="auto" Height="auto"  FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Navy">
                                                    <TextBlock.Resources>
                                                        <local:TaxId2PercentageConverter x:Key="TaxPerConv" />
                                                    </TextBlock.Resources>

                                                    <TextBlock.Text>
                                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TaxPerConv}" Mode="OneWay">
                                                            <Binding Path="DCIM.Lst_Tax" />
                                                            <Binding Path="TaxId"/>
                                                        </MultiBinding>
                                                    </TextBlock.Text>
                                                </TextBlock>
                                            </ContentControl>
                                        </DataGridCell>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

A snapshot of the relevant portion of the ViewModel is as under:-

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
 HexaEntities DbContext = new HexaEntities();
 private List<hexa_tax> p_Lst_Tax = new List<hexa_tax>();
 public List<hexa_tax> Lst_Tax
     {
        get { return p_Lst_Tax; }
        set
        {
            if(p_Lst_Tax!=value)
            {
                p_Lst_Tax = value;
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Lst_Tax");

            }
        }
    } 


 public MyViewModel ()
        {
          Lst_Tax = DbContext.hexa_tax.ToList<hexa_tax>();
        }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChangedEvent(string Property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Property));
        }
    }
 }
```

Lst_tax is a `List<T>` ie a property on my ViewModel which i want to pass to this TextBlock,but it the converter,it gives me an exception saying:
 Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1

Comment: @Clemens:yes,it is a property of my ViewModel named DCIM

Comment: Did you search StackOverflow for "Unable to cast object of type MS.Internal.NamedObject". There is certainly something wrong with your binding(s). Without seeing the view model declarations your question can't be answered.

Comment: So what you show now is that you have a `Current_Item_Price_Details` property, which is a collection of a not shown class with a `DCIM` property, which contains an instance of `MyViewModel`? Your question is a mess, sorry.

Comment: Besides that, I guess your actual problem is that you have a DataGridCell and a ContentControl in the DataTemplate in the CellTemplate property. Both don't make sense. Instead, the TextBlock should be the top level element in the DataTemplate.

Comment: Please post the code of your converter class.